# NSException error when presenting UITableViewController from an other place modally

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I present my `UITableViewController` from an other place modaly in the app I get an error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Same code works in the default project from Apple, what is the problem?

```
import UIKit

class SettingViewController: UITableViewController {
    let fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Peach"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section)"
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.section).\(indexPath.row): \(fruit)"

            return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Put in an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) to see where it's crashing. I suspect you didn't create a cell with the identifier "TextCell"

Comment: The reason for the error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: the Breakpoint is at
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad() I added

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Comment: I suspect that this actually did solve the problem for OP, so it does provide an answer to the question. But the reuseIdentifier in your code is "TextCell" and here you're registering a cell with the identifier "reuseIdentifier".